# Why are noac/lookupcache NFS v4 mount options not allowed?

Tags: nfs, nfs4

I was trying some mount options from this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/638601/nfs-caching-issue), however, whenever, I have attempted using them I received this error when remounting:

```
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Invalid argument
mount.nfs4: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

When remounting, these are options that will are reported to be used by mount: `"rw,noexec,remount,soft,intr,port=2049,sec=sys,lookupcache=none"`

What is going on here?  Are these options not supported by NFSv4?

Answer (score 0):

Oh weird, I was unable to "remount" using these new options, but restarting the `netfs` daemon allows for the NFS mount to be remounted with the new options.